# UWP APPXBundle issue to bundle languages

Tags: c#, tfs, uwp, msbuild, makeappx

Into my `MyProject.AppPackage.wapproj,` i have changed `AppxBundle` from `Always` to `Never`, to have all resources in one bundle (mostly based to have all languages available at runtime).
Changed line it's the third.

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <DefaultLanguage>fr-CH</DefaultLanguage>
    <AppxBundle>Never</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I have changed my TFS Build Solution task removing

```
/p:AppxBundle=Always
```

now it looks

```
/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)" 
/p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\$(BuildConfiguration)" 
/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload
```

but now my build fails with this error

```
   2018-08-30T06:58:05.0184996Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3510,5): Error APPX0002: Task 'CreateAppStoreContainer' failed. Could not find file 'C:\Agent2\_work\100\s\MyProject.App\bin\Upload\MyProject.App_2.0.0.14435_x86\MyProject.App_2.0.0.14435_x86.appxsym'.
```

If i remove my changes `<AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>` and adding MSBuilds Arguments /p:AppxBundle=Always It come back to works, but not as I want to bundle all resources in one package.

How could i solve it?

I have tried also with [to use priconfig.default.xml and priconfig.packaging.xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/build-resources-into-app-package) but problem is not solved, I have this error

```
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.0128926Z _CreateResourcePackages:
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.0128926Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64\MakeAppx.exe pack /r /l /h sha256 /m C:\Agent2\_work\100\s\MyProject.AppPackage\bin\x86\Release\ForBundle\AppxManifest.xml /f obj\x86\Release\split.scale-125.map.txt /o /p C:\Agent2\_work\100\s\MyProject.AppPackage\bin\x86\Release\MyProject.AppPackage_2.0.0.14459_scale-125.appx  
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.0755831Z ##[error]MakeAppx(0,0): Error : The mapping file can't be parsed.  The error occurs at line 8.
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.0755831Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=MakeAppx;linenumber=0;columnnumber=0;code=;]The mapping file can't be parsed.  The error occurs at line 8.
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.0755831Z MakeAppx : error : The mapping file can't be parsed.  The error occurs at line 8. [C:\Agent2\_work\100\s\MyProject.AppPackage\MyProject.AppPackage.wapproj]
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.0755831Z ##[error]MakeAppx(0,0): Error : Package creation failed.
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.0755831Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=MakeAppx;linenumber=0;columnnumber=0;code=;]Package creation failed.
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.0755831Z MakeAppx : error : Package creation failed. [C:\Agent2\_work\100\s\MyProject.AppPackage\MyProject.AppPackage.wapproj]
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.0755831Z ##[error]MakeAppx(0,0): Error : 0x8007000b - An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.0755831Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=MakeAppx;linenumber=0;columnnumber=0;code=;]0x8007000b - An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.0755831Z MakeAppx : error : 0x8007000b - An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. [C:\Agent2\_work\100\s\MyProject.AppPackage\MyProject.AppPackage.wapproj]
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.1223110Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=10c2f9a3-d35c-44bd-8001-f19223d98f3b;parentid=4705ecb4-9eb8-44ae-9593-df9eca329231;type=Build;result=Failed;finishtime=2018-08-30T11:27:28.1223110Z;progress=100;state=Completed;parentid=4705ecb4-9eb8-44ae-9593-df9eca329231;name=;]
    2018-08-30T11:27:28.1223110Z Done Building Project "C:\Agent2\_work\100\s\MyProject.AppPackage\MyProject.AppPackage.wapproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```